# M2 Add canonical tag to Advanced Search page

Tags: magento-2.1, canonical

In my theme I have a folder Magento_AdvancedSearch. How can I add a canonical tag to this page via XML?

Edit: I have made a file catalogsearch_index_index.xml with the code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Advanced Search - Test</title>
    <link rel="canonical" src="http://www.extenderstore.com.au/catalogsearch/advanced/" src_type="url"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Create a file catalogsearch_advanced_index.xml and place it in the layout folder of Magento_CatalogSearch in your theme. Use the same code in the question.