# M2.3.5.1-p1 Add canonical tag to Advanced Search page

Tags: seo, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p1, canonical

I have a problem where my SEO tool finds `/catalogsearch/advanced` as no canonical link. **I tried doing this** [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198090/m2-add-canonical-tag-to-advanced-search-page?newreg=3d7f95ef559246cc87fb4f1b41b8bb63), which is basically the same question, but It wouldn't work for me, even after recompiling the whole shop and clearing the cache.
So, basically, I need to add a canonical link to `/catalogsearch/advanced`, but I can't get it to work. I tried editing the *catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml*, *catalogsearch_advanced_index.xml* and *catalogsearch_result_index.xml*
Here's a piece of the code for catalogsearch_advanced_index:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <link rel="canonical" src="https://mainpage.com/catalogsearch/advanced" src_type="url"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem">
        <type>link_rel</type>
        <name>https://mainpage.com/catalogsearch/advanced</name>
     </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Hey, Im kindda new, do I put that in the catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml or catalogsearch_advanced_index.xml? Also, inside which XML tags?